# 2000 AD comic story line where "repetitive thumping sound heard in people's heads" saves them from apocalypse

Tags: episode-identification, 2000ad

I am looking to identify a *[2000 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_AD_(comics))* story where the protagonist is able to broadcast a repetitive thumping. A group of people who hear the sound in their heads set off from the Earth to the moon (?) to colonize. This saves them from what I believe is the destruction of the planet.

This would have been most likely published in the mid to late '80s.

Comment: Was it a serial story or a one-off like a time-twister or future-shock?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_(comics)?

Comment: I beleive it was a one-off story.

Comment: In colour or black & white?

Comment: "2000AD" is the *name* of the publication, not a date.  Don't change it!